# How to convert a stream of bytes to another encoding?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to convert a stream of bytes with [MultiByteToWideChar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) WinAPI function.

Documentation says function fails with ERROR_NO_UNICODE_TRANSLATION on incomplete strings (no trailing byte in multibyte encoded string). How do I prevent this error? The only way that comes to mind is not to convert the last multibyte character of input buffer (using [IsDBCSLeadByteEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318667%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to locate it).

Are there better solutions to convert a stream of bytes?

Comment: Which code pages you use? In which form you receive the data? I hope from the start to the end and not vice versa.

Comment: The code should work with all codepages supported by Windows platforms. I receive the data in multibyte or singlebyte encoding and want to process it internally in wide form, converting it to locale-specific encoding on output (after processing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you can just use [CharNextExA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647470%28VS.85%29.aspx) to move to the next character position in the input stream. In the way you can get some characters and convert there together in the UNICODE string with respect of [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28VS.85%29.aspx). After you have the UNICODE text fragment you can convert it in another code page using [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx).

**UPDATED**: I am sure the process of receiving the stream of the input data is much more slowly as the decoding of data with respect of [CharNextExA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647470%28VS.85%29.aspx), [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx). For example if you use a buffer on the stack like `WCHAR szBuffer[4096]` and `TCHAR szDestBuffer[4096]` then you will be able to decode 1K of input data very quickly. So I suppose that **the total time of working of your whole program** will be almost indented from the usage of these three functions.

Moreover, I am not sure that you have any alternative. I don't know any reliable way to start decoding of the text either from the beginning of at the end of the text. Probably other people has another idea...

Comment: I need more efficient approach - the data chunks are very big and I don't want to call function for each symbol. Is there a way to reduce a number of calls?

Comment: It seems to me that another way is impossible if you want support all codepages supported by Windows platforms. In the documentation of `IsDBCSLeadByteEx` you can read: "Lead byte values are specific to each distinct DBCS. Some byte values can appear in a single code page as both the lead and trail byte of a DBCS character. Thus, IsDBCSLeadByteEx can only indicate a potential lead byte value.". So The sequential scan of data with `CharNextExA` seems the only safe way. Just verify whether you will fill any performance changes from the usage of `CharNextExA`. It is quickly. `CharPrevExA` is slow

Comment: Is analysing a tail of 10 bytes at the end of 10000 bytes buffer with CharPrevExA() slower than processing the whole buffer with CharNextExA()? Will CharPrevExA work properly being given a middle of character as lpCurrentChar argument?

Comment: @Basilevs: I wrote you before, that you should use `CharNextExA` because `CharPrevExA` is slow. Both `CharNextExA` and `CharPrevExA` will work **only if you start** with the correct character begin. So you **have to** use on from the function. Because of the performance reason you should use `CharNextExA`.